# How to create a .PDF from my .net web page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, pdf-generation

Im using visual studio 2010 (VB) to build a web site for my customers.  They have a simple web form that they fill out to log electronically minutes of meeting notes.  They would like to have this web form converted into a .PDF file when completed and e-mailed round to the list of users.

Can anyone point me in the direction of any tools that are able to help with converting the data from the web page into a .PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of numerous libraries to generate PDFs from your pages. There is a [walkthrough here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx) (it uses [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), but others are available - have a Google around).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i have reviewed the link and this is for C#. Im looking for a tool for VB.

Comment: I have managed to find some sample code for iTextSharp in VB and will see if i can develop this sample code for my site.  many thanks.

Comment: Cool.

You might find a C# to VB.net conversion tool useful. Here's one provided by the good people at Telerik: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a library such as PDFSharp to create a PDF manually, with the data you need.

http://www.pdfsharp.com/

Trying to convert the html & css to a PDF normally is very flaky and I would say the best option would be to create the document separately using a PDF library (read PDFSharp) and give the user that.

Demo code for Vb.net:

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample-VB.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: many thanks, i have taken a look and can see that this is suitable for C#.  Im looking for a tool for VB.

Comment: It's just a library, I wrote code in VB.net for PDF sharp. Just add the reference to the dll and check out: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample-VB.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use Syncfusion Essential PDF.

Product link
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/pdf

Online demo link:
http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/pdf/Import%20and%20Export/HtmlToPdf/CS/Default.aspx

Comment: manay thanks but i am looking for a tool suitable with VB.

Comment: It can be used with both c# and vb. Check the sample link: http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/pdf/Import%20and%20Export/HtmlToPdf/vb/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of template (and I think you have, cause you should generate your pdf from single web-form) you can use Crystal Reports and export it to the pdf file.
I need more attractive design of my pdf-doc, so I use [ABCPdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) + HtmlAgilityPack + GeckoEngine. It allows me generate pdf from html file. Note that ABCPdf isn't free

Comment: many thanks for your help.  We used to use Crystal reports but this replaced this with MSoft reporting services a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have any fancy charts etc you can use free pdf converters to generate pdf.
however if you want charts etc and would like to work with them, then go for "www.pdftrond.com" or Using HiQPdf tool.

HiQPdf tool has Startup License Price: $395.00 for single machine on a single application

PDFTron is around $800